# IPTABLES PREROUTING all traffic in subnet tranparently to proxy, except for

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

I have a firewall between 192.168.255.0 and 172.16.255.0. Both /24. 192.168.255.0 get DNAT'd to a proxy server @ 172.16.255.5:8080. I want this to continue however I have a web server 172.16.255.50 that I want direct connection to for testing. I've tried this statement, but iptables keeps erroring when trying to add it

```
iptables -I PREROUTING -i eth1 -d \! 172.16.255.50 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.255.5:8080
```

Thanks!!

Comment: This would work better, if you pasted the exact error you get...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues here

1. You left off `-t nat`, so its trying to add to the `PREROUTING` chain in the `filter` table, which doesn't exist.
2. The 'not' (`!`) has to go before the `-d`.

Working solution:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth1 \! -d 172.16.255.50 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.255.5:8080
```

---

Alternatively, another way of doing things like this is to put a rule in before that one which matches the exception traffic and does nothing with it. Iptables stops once it hits the first matching rule, so it never gets to the later rule.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -d 172.16.255.50 -p tcp --dport 80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.255.5:8080
```